# How to find values of column status that have 8 but still do not have 9

Tags: sql, subquery, window-functions

Iam working on project and i need to find in table one column named status (this col have values from 1-12), i want to find all values that below to the condition (if the status have 8 but still do not have 9), for more information :

Original table :

```
    File_name           id      status  Execution_number
    Live_package1.zip   333      3      4444443434343
    Live_package2.zip   444      7      8888888886767
    Live_package1.zip   333      8      4444443434343
    Live_package2.zip   444      8      8888888886767
    Live_package2.zip   444     10      8888888886767
    Live_package3.zip   666      8      9999999999999
    Live_package4.zip   111      9      3333333333333
```

The desired result

```
File_name            id       status    Execution_number
Live_package1.zip   333         8        4444443434343
Live_package3.zip   666         8        9999999999999
```

iam using the following code , but I did not received the result what I expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_doc_state
WHERE status       =8
AND NOT(status  !=9);
```

Comment: Why did you add the condition `NOT(status  !=9)`? Just leave it... It's sufficient to just ast `WHERE status = 8` which implies that `status` is not `9`.

Comment: Because every** id** have more than one status (1-12) and i need just the id which have 8 status but still do not have the 9 or 10 status

Comment: Don't tag 3 completely different RDBMS. Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. I have removed all the conflicting tags, [edit] your question with the correct one *only*.

Comment: `where status = 8` only selects those rows where the column has the value `8`. So the it will never be `9` - `not (status <> 9)` is the same as `status = 9`  and `status = 8 and status = 9` will never be true

Comment: I suspect that the OPs sample data doesn't tell the true story, @deHaar , and that a row (say id `666`) could also have a row with a status of `9`; the sample just doesn't give a good picture of the real problem.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, that's what he clarified some comments above... Then I would naively use some `NOT EXISTS` subquery first and check if I can optimize that afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> select * From tbl_doc_state;

FIL         ID     STATUS EXECUTION_NUMBER
--- ---------- ---------- ----------------
lp1        333          3               43
lp2        444          7               67
lp1        333          8               43
lp2        444         10               67
lp3        666          8               99
lp4        111          9               33

6 rows selected.

SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id,
  3            max(status) max_status
  4     from tbl_doc_state
  5     group by id
  6    )
  7  select a.*
  8  from tbl_doc_state a join temp t on a.id = t.id
  9                                  and a.status = t.max_status
 10  where t.max_status = 8;

FIL         ID     STATUS EXECUTION_NUMBER
--- ---------- ---------- ----------------
lp1        333          8               43
lp3        666          8               99

SQL>
```

Comment: it is work perfectly , You are the best thank you so much another question i want to group by id , can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude rows that have status 8 but there are *other* rows with the same id but with the status 9, use a `not` exists condition:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_doc_state t1
WHERE status = 8
and not exists (select *
                from tbl_doc_state t2
                where t2.id = t1.id 
                  and t2.status >= 9);
```

Comment: OP commented (question-comment) that he wants alle id's that have one `status = 8` and no `status >= 9`...

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell which column should used to order the records. If you are using `status` for this, then the query is just:

```
select * from tbl_doc_state where status = 8
```

*If* you have another ordering column, say `sort_id`, then the question makes more sense. You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, max(case when status = 9 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id order by sort_id) has_status_9
    from mytable t
) t 
where status = 8 and has_status_9 = 0
```

Comment: That why i love stackoverflow , because he have a lot royal and smart  people like you .. thank you so much , it is help a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

With window function `MAX()`:

```
select t.File_name, t.id, t.status, t.Execution_number
from (
    select t.*, max(t.status) over(partition by t.id) max_status
    from tbl_doc_state t
) t 
where max_status = 8 and status = max_status
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9e5dba4444b01482d9b0f775bd33bad).
Results:

```
> File_name         |  id | status | Execution_number
> :---------------- | --: | -----: | :---------------
> Live_package1.zip | 333 |      8 | 4444443434343   
> Live_package3.zip | 666 |      8 | 9999999999999
```

Comment: It is so helpful and fast when i run it , thanks a lot